# How to find the total difference of this composition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$g:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2:g(x,y)=(e^{x-y},x-y)$.

$f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2: f(u,v)=(e^v+\tan(1-u),v^2-u^2)$

I composed the functions and then differentiated $f\circ g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, but what I want to do is to express that in terms of the derivatives of $f$ and $g$, as you do when you draw a tree diagram (basically I want to find that tree), but I couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x,y):=f\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr)$, and denote the partial derivatives of the $i^{\rm th}$ component function of $g$ with respect to $x$ by $g_{i.x}$, and similarly for $f$. Then one has (this is the multivariate chain rule)
$$\left[\matrix{h_{1.x}&h_{1.y} \cr h_{2.x}&h_{2.y}\cr}\right]_{(x,y)}=\left[\matrix{f_{1.u}&f_{1.v} \cr f_{2.u}&f_{2.v}\cr}\right]_{(u,v):=g(x,y)}\ 
\left[\matrix{g_{1.x}&g_{1.y} \cr g_{2.x}&g_{2.y}\cr}\right]_{(x,y)}\ .$$
This matrix product is the "tree" you are after. It is important that you don't effectuate the substitution $(u,v):=g(x,y)$ in the first factor on the right hand side, because then you would only arrive at the expressions you have already computed before asking the question..